# how to fetch data from sqlite by name

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I just started learning of android and come to section of Database and I inserted same record in it but now I want to fetch data from database only by name and display it in textview.
Help me 
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please follow developer document.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

  // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
  // you will actually use after this query.
String[] projection = {
FeedEntry._ID,
FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE,
FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE
};

// Filter results WHERE "title" = 'My Title'
String selection = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { "My Title" };

// How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
String sortOrder =
FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + " DESC";

Cursor cursor = db.query(
FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,                     // The table to query
projection,                               // The columns to return
selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
null,                                     // don't group the rows
null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
sortOrder                                 // The sort order
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You access data by using a **query** which returns a **`Cursor`**.

A **`Cursor`** is like a spreadsheet table that contains **columns** and **rows**.

You tell the query what columns you want and imply the rows that will be returned via an optional **`WHERE`** statement.

The simplest of queries is base upon the SQL `SELECT * FROM <table>;`. This will select all columns (i.e. **`*`** means **all** columns) from the table as specified by `<table>` ( where  would be replaced by a valid table name).

If you want specific columns then **``` *`` should be replaced with a comma delimited list e.g. ```SELECT name, address FROM `would return a **`Cursor`** containing all the rows from the table with only the **name** and **address** columns from the table specified by``.

If you want to filter the rows returned then you can add a **WHERE** clause. e.g. `SELECT name,address FROM <table> WHERE name = 'Fred'`, would return a **`Cursor`** containing only the rows that have *Fred* as the name column with only the **name** and **address** columns.

You cannot just type the SQL statments you need to either use the SQLiteDatabase `rawQuery` or `query` methods if you need to return a cursor.

### Using `rawQuery`

**`rawQuery`** takes two parameters, the first being the SQL as a string, the second optional arguments (not covered here, so **null** will be used).

To obtain a **`Cursor`** with columns name and address and with only rows that have Fred you could use, assuming the table is called **mytable** :-

```
`Cursor mycursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name,address FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Fred'";);`
```

*where **db** is an instance of an SQLiteDatabase object.*

However, **`rawQuery`** is not recommended as it is open SQL injection. rather it is recommended only for situations where it has to be used.

### Using `query`

**`query`** has a number of overload variations as can be found here [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

For this example `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)` will be used.

- `String table`, is the name of the table to be queried.
- `String[] columns`, is an array of column names.
- `String selection` is the where clause (null for no where clause).
- `String[] selectionArgs` is an array of arguments that replace the **?** placeholder.
- The rest of the parameters will be null as these are features that are not being utilised.

As such the code could be :-

```
        String tablename = "mytable";
        String[] columns = {"name", "address"};
        String whereclause = "name=?"; //note use of placeholder ?
        String[] whereargs = {"Fred"};
        Cursor mycursor = db.query(tablename,
                columns,
                whereclause,
                whereargs,
                null,null,null
        );
```

*where **db** is an instance of an SQLiteDatabase object.*

### Accessing the Cursor

`mycursor` contains the data or perhaps not if there isn't a column with the name Fred.

The number of rows in the cursor can be obtained by using:-
    int rowsincursor = mycursor.getCount();

***Note! A returned `Cursor` will not be null.*** (a very common mistake)

To access the data you have to **move** through the **`Cursor`**. Initially the **`Cursor`** is *before the first row*. If you only expect or want the only/first row then you can use the **`Cursor`** **`moveToFirst`** method.

*See [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) for more move... methods etc*

Once the **`Cursor`** is appropriately positioned you can use **`Cursor`** get methods to get the data. e.g. **`getString(int columnindex)`** will return the data as a String. columnindex is a 0 based offset of the column to be accessed. Using the **`Cursor`**'s **`getColumnIndex(String columnname)`** can be used to eliminate errors made by miscalculating offsets.

As such the following could be used to set a **`TextView`** (note intentionally over cautious)

```
        if (mycursor.getCCount() > 0) {
            if (mycursor.moveToFirst()) {
                mytextview.setText(mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            }
        }
        mycursor.close() // You should always close a cursor when done with it.
```